# C++: issue with vector and random_shuffle

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of objects from a class I've created, and each object contains 4 variables: two doubles, an int, and a bool. The int is being used as an ID number so I can keep track of which object is which within the vector, while member functions of another class I've created perform calculations on the doubles and manipulate the bool (true and false). I'm using random_shuffle to reorder the vector such that two random objects from the vector interact with each other, but this is where I'm getting a problem. After random_shuffle operates, the two doubles and bool return values properly (i think), but the ID number int is returned as gibberish (-858993460) for every ID number except for the object with the first ID number. Here is a generic version of the code. Can anyone help me out in getting the ID number to print? It is greatly appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    CalculationClass CalculationObject;

    int vectorsize; // number of objects from class "Object" to create
    vectorsize = PromptForVectorSize(); // user inputs number of objects to create
    std::vector<Object> ObjectVector(vectorsize, Object() );    

    int iterations;    // number of loops to run 
    iterations = PromptForIterations(); // user inputs number of loops



    for(int z = 0; z<ObjectVector.size(); z++) // gives signed/unsigned warning
    {   // Gives each object an ID number //
    CalculationObject.EstablishIDNumbers(ObjectVector[z], z);
    }   


    for(int i = 0; i<iterations; i++)
    {
    cout << "========================================="     << endl;
    cout << "RUN NUMBER " << i+1 << endl;


        std::random_shuffle (ObjectVector.begin(), ObjectVector.end());


        for(size_t x = 0; x<ObjectVector.size(); x+=2)          
        {

            cout << ObjectVector[x].getIDNumber() << endl;
            cout << ObjectVector[x].getObjectDouble() << endl;
            cout << ObjectVector[x+1].getIDNumber() << endl;
                            cout << ObjectVector[x+1].getObjectDouble() << endl;

            CalculationObject.Function(ObjectVector[x], ObjectVector[x+1]);

                            cout << ObjectVector[x].getIDNumber() << endl;
            cout << ObjectVector[x].getObjectDouble() << endl;
            cout << ObjectVector[x+1].getIDNumber() << endl;
                            cout << ObjectVector[x+1].getObjectDouble() << endl;

            cout << "=========================================" << endl;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the definitions of `Object` and `CalculationClass::EstablishIDNumbers()` it's going to be hard to diagnose this.

Comment: void CalculationClass::EstablishIDNumbers(Object &Object, int &i) const
{
 Object.setIDNumber(i+1);
}

Comment: From the Object class
int OpecAgent::setAgentIDNumber(int  idnumber)        
 AgentIDNumber = idnumber;
 return AgentIDNumber;       
}

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider for example `vectorsize` is 5. After the random shuffle operation -

```
for(size_t x = 0; x<ObjectVector.size(); x+=2)          
{
    ObjectVector[x].getIDNumber()
    ObjectVector[x+1].getIDNumber()
    ....
```

The values of iteration variable `x` are going to be 0, 2, 4. When it is 4, the condition satisfies (4<5). But the real problem is you are accessing vector elements at 4, 5 indexes. The valid indexes for a vector of size 5 is 0 to 4. So, the program has undefined behavior.